# Issue accessing variable outside of function scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm pulling data from an XML feed. That is all working correctly but I need `productIDs` available outside the function.

```
    // Get feed data
    $.get('example-feed.xml', function (data) {

    var $xml = $(data);

    // Collect array of product IDs
    var productIDs = [];

    // extract ids from xml
    $xml.find("item").each(function() {

      var $this = $(this)

      item = {
        id: $this.find("id").text()
      }

      // get the id
      var itemID = item.id;

      // push ids to array
      productIDs.push(itemID);

    });

    console.log(productIDs); // Works as expected

  });

  console.log(productIDs); // Undefined, also as expected
```

How can I adjust my function to work like that?

```
    example = function(){

      var productIDs = "my content ids"

      return {'productIDs': productIDs}

    }

    var retrive = example();

    console.log(retrive.productIDs);
```

Comment: If the function is asynchronous (AJAX), you can't return a value, you have to use callbacks or promises. Your second example works fine

Comment: try `var productIDs = $.get(.....)` with what you want to return at the bottom of your function like `return productIDs` and then console.log(productIDs) right after. Does that work?

Comment: @Juan isn't the `function(data)` being passed to `get` the callback? Or am I missing something?

Comment: *"but I need productIDs available outside the function."* Put the code that needs to access `productIDs` into a function and pass `productIDs` to that function. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196). *"How can I adjust my function to work like that?"* You can't `$.get` is asynchronous. You cannot return the response.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do this, but the best thing here is to use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), because JQuery's get is usually asynchronous function and you have to wait for it's completion to get product ids

You may do it like this

```
function fetchThings () {
  return new Promise(function (yes, no) {
    $.get('example-feed.xml', function (data) {

      // some code here

      console.log(productIDs); // Works as expected
      yes(productIDs);
    });
  });
}

fetchThings().then(function (productIDs) {
   // do stuff with prodcut ids here
});
```

The other way to do it would be making your $.get call synchronous, so replace it by

```
var productIDs;
$.ajax({url: 'example-feed.xml', type: "GET", async: false, success: function (data) { 
// process productIDs here
}});

// use productIDs here
```

**Update**:

Here is a snippet of async ajax, click run to check

```js
var postIDs;

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
  method: 'GET',
  async: false,
  success: function(posts) {
    postIDs = posts.map(function (p) { return p.id; });
  }
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(postIDs));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah thanks Ammar. Your second approach looks like a good fit to me. However I'm still getting `undefined` ? You sure your second example is correct?

Comment: Oh yeah you are right, there was a mistake in the code, in `$.ajax` async should be false, i wrote the opposite. Now have corrected the code, please check again :) @MischaColley

Comment: I have also added a snippet here as an example, also check that

Comment: Do not mention synchronous AJAX, it's deprecated